Ubuntu PI5 - PCI nvme not running at Gen 3
I am new to Ubuntu, however I did get Ubuntu installed on the NVMe drive and the Raspberry Pi5 is booting up correctly on it. The question is about NVMe speed. I am only getting ~412 MB/sec read and write speeds. On Pi OS you can edit config.txt file to double the speed. I did the same edit to config.txt in Ubuntu. I entered the following: dtparam=pciex1. I even tried dtparam=nvme and dtparam=pciex1_gen=3. Unlike when I ran test in Pi OS I don't see if the drive is running Gen 2 or Gen 3.  Can someone help me upgrade PCI to Gen 3 on Ubuntu Pi OS?

How in the world did you actually get Ubuntu runnning on the Pi 5 from NVMe? I flashed Ubuntu to my NVMe drive, inserted it into my PCI to NVMe adapter attached to my pi, and it doesn't boot or even recognize my NVMe drive. What did you do to get ubuntu booting off of an NVMe drive?
